# Adding a "touch of human" to Q/As

Tags: discussion, edits, asking-questions, blog

So in recent [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/) [posts](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/week-2-of-the-summer-of-love-researching-comments/) from SE regarding friendliness of posts, the idea of adding a touch of "human" realness was so very briefly discussed.

I've noticed a few of my questions/answers (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599105/sdl-theory-and-surfaces)) have been edited by peers (non-moderators) removing certain 'human touches' to the question. Of course, none of these touches hinder the original question's integrity or relevance. **No, this does not include "Thanks [in advance!]" or smiley faces.**

Is it wrong to show that there is, in fact, a human being with qualities other than sounding like a drone sitting behind the computer?

Comment: What does your edit mean, "No, this does not include 'thanks [in advance!]'"?  Maybe you'd better post a link to a specific example.

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting. This is in response to the ideas presented in the linked blog posts.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Done.

Comment: [Downvotes are different on Meta.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Ah, didn't realize. I don't come on here enough.

Comment: [Here's an edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/139123/revisions) on one of my answers.

Comment: @JimmyPena - Never mentioned smiley faces either.

Comment: Refer to [JW8](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140903/147645)'s answer. Content which can be safely removed without affecting the substance of the question as it relates to the subject of the site may be removed. Yes, even smileys.

Comment: @JimmyPena - I'm not disagreeing with you. I'm saying that by "human touch" I didn't mean smilies.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you either. But I think you are making an arbitrary distinction. Why smilies and "thanks!" are off-topic for your question, I don't understand. We all get our posts edited. Sometimes it is trivial and feels like the human element is being edited out. I think it's best to simply move on.

Comment: @JimmyPena - I'm not saying they're off topic, either. I don't care they got edited, I'm asking the question to be more clear on the subject. I'm not asking out of anger that my one question got edited by someone.

Comment: I'm trying to help you, but every time I or someone makes a suggestion, you move the goal line. Good luck, I hope you find what you need.

Answer (score 10):

The policy is this:

1. Hi, thanks, signatures and taglines are discouraged in all posts.
2. If an editor sees these, *and is willing to fix the other problems in the post (spelling, grammar, etc.),* they are free to remove said taglines, signatures, etc.

Think of your question (and it's answers) as a mini blog post.  Would you put "Thanks in Advance" in one of your own blog posts?  No, you wouldn't.

We want to keep all posts on Stack Overflow as noise-free as possible.  Saying "thanks" is nice, but upvoting is better.  Putting your name in your post is redundant; your user card displays your name on every post you make.

---

Anyway, to address the linked post, the words that were removed by the editor didn't really add anything to your question. If you're really interested in social lubrication, one of the best things you can do on Stack Overflow is to get to the point, as quickly as possible.

Comment: I never mentioned saying "thanks". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599105/sdl-theory-and-surfaces

Comment: Why are you asking three questions in the same post?

Comment: a) They are related to the basic use/design of SDL surfaces and b) they were too generic to add to their own question. I felt it fit to create a single question addressing all of them.

Comment: None of your questions are very good.  1) Can be answered Yes or No  2) Too broad and subjective, 3) Possibly.  Oh, did you mean "how?"

Comment: They're still questions nonetheless. Questions I cannot find anywhere else on the internet, as stated in the question as well.

Comment: You need to formulate your questions better.  One way you can do this is to *show your research.*

Comment: Also, that just further proves my point as to why they weren't good questions to separate into their own questions.

Comment: There was no research to show - As I said in the OP, I couldn't find any relative information related to those questions in the first place.

Comment: Anyway, to answer your original question, the words that were removed by the editor didn't really add anything to your question.  If you're really interested in social lubrication, one of the best things you can do on Stack Overflow is to *get to the point,* as quickly as possible.

Comment: Perhaps not the "simple, simple", but adding that I couldn't come up with anything on google or that I didn't know what keywords to use were perfectly relevant; someone could have suggested some keywords or provided some vocabulary to search with.

Comment: That's not really what we're here for, although I will occasionally post a productive Google Search in a comment to help people out.

Comment: Then what is SO here for? It's here to help people find answers to questions and as a catalyst to research. If someone can, along with the original questions, suggest keywords to help me further my research off of SO instead of posting questions that are not "very good", then I would definitely say that is an element of a successful answer.

Comment: I would agree in the sense that asking a questions specifically calling for keywords to use in a search for another question shouldn't be on SO for the fact that it would then be subjective and a discussion.

Comment: Does [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_blit) answer your first question?

Comment: Yes, which was already pointed out by someone else. I wasn't finding it because I was assuming it was an SDL-specific term, thus I was typing in "SDL blitting" and only finding _how_ to blit, not exactly what it was, thus I added the note about keywords.

Comment: It was the first match to a Google Search for "blitting".

Comment: I **just said** I was adding "sdl" to the keywords. Google "sdl blitting". I didn't think to search for "blitting" because I was assuming it was SDL specific. Why are we breaking down the intent of the question? Completely irrelevant to this thread.

Comment: The intent of the question speaks directly to the efficacy of the edit.  It is quite telling that several people are willing to help you in comments, but nobody's willing to post an answer because your question is essentially unanswerable in a QA format.  In short, we favor carefully crafted, well worded, *answerable* questions over social lubrication.  We prefer questions that we can answer with our software development expertise, not questions having to do with Google-fu.

Comment: Actually nobody is answering the question for several reasons - one, it was posted within the past 2 days, two it's about SDL which is not as broad as a general C++ question for example, and three, as pointed out by the first answer, they're not sure of the answer.

Comment: Most answerable questions get answers within 30 minutes of being posted on Stack Overflow.  Stack Overflow is not a forum; if you came here with expectations from other online forums, you might want to approach this format with a fresh perspective.

Comment: I know the difference between a forum and SO. So I posted a question that may be lacking in structure - sorry. However, _this_ meta question can apply to any question.

Answer (score 7):

My reading of the general community consensus is that succinct "professional" answers are generally preferred for Q&A. As such, some editors may remove extraneous text/human touches that don't add to the question or answer's integrity or relevance.